# Hotspot failed authentication on Android - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager, kde, android, ap-hotspot

Am using Ubuntu 16.04 , am creating shared wifi hotspot from my ubuntu desktop it works fine if i create it without password and it connect to my android device ok, but when i tried to create/edit a new connection and put a WPA & WPA 2 Password the connection to my android device failed. It keeps on authenticate and tried to save the connection but later on it failed.

*I tried with kde-connect but the result is still the same, but kde used to work fine while i was using ubuntu 15.10 with the same android device.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to get it to work after spending some time trying different settings. This is what I have done:

1. I set the security to "WEP 40/128-bit Key (Hex or ASCII)".
2. Then I chose a key of length exactly 13, as this is the only key-length for which the save button would get activated. This sounds extremely weird, but it could have something to do with the encryption algorithm or something, or just a funny bug.
3. Leave the WEP index to 1 and Authentication set to Open System

I know this is a rather old question but I think people might still find this to be useful.

Comment: WEP is barely better than no encryption at all since over a decade though. I'd argue that it's worse because it leads users to falsely believe that there's working encryption in place.

Comment: Thank you for noting this as I had no idea about it. However, in my case strong encryption is not needed, it should only make it difficult to just simply connect to the network.

Comment: Since it's relatively simple to recover the key of a WEP-encrypted wireless network (half a minute to a few minutes depending on the network speed and computation power of your laptop or smartphone) it's just as simple to connect to its access point. The biggest hurdle is that you need a wireless adapter driver and firmware that allow operation in "promiscuous mode". Even so those are available for $15–$50 at consumer electronics stores.

Comment: Thank you again. It is still OK for my needs as the average user won't bother doing as much to hack into a wireless network, but as you explained it is almost no effort to decrypt it for those with little computer experience. Nevertheless, I would still prefer to use this than no encryption at all, until the problem in Ubuntu gets fixed...